# postgresql concat variable with string and insert into JSONB

Tags: postgresql

in my postgre SQL statement I need to concat an ID int with string and insert it as JSON value into JSONB column. My query is as follows:

```
DO
$$
  DECLARE  
    myID int = 555;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (status, url)
    VALUES(0,
           '{
             "alias": "XXX",
             "pageUrl": "https://example.com/?myID="' || myID || '}'::jsonb
          );
  END
$$;
```

But this query fails with error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"`. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to deal with JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `json_build_object` to prepare your json :

```
DO
$$
  DECLARE  
    myID int = 555;
    myJson json;
  BEGIN
    myJson = json_build_object('alias', 'XXX', 'pageUrl', 'https://example.com/?myID=' || myID) ;
    
    INSERT INTO mytable (status, url)
    VALUES(0, myJson);
  END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable(
    Status INT,
    URL jsonb 
    );
    
    
    INSERT INTO mytable (status, url)
    SELECT 0,
           CONCAT('{
            "alias": "XXX",
            "pageUrl": "https://example.com/?myID=', 555 ,
           '"}')::jsonb
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

| status | url |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"alias":"XXX","pageUrl":"https://example.com/?myID=555"} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)